# Insert new xml attribute into MS Word xml document element

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to prevent word document fields getting updated by setting a lock using the field `w:fldLock`. I have an `xml` file which contains the node `w:fldSimple`. Whenever I find this node I want to set the attribute `w:fldLock` to this node. To achieve this I want to use XSLT transformation. Can you please advise me the sample XSL Transformation?

Example xml Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<w:hdr mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
   <w:p w:rsidR="00235C27" w:rsidRDefault="00235C27">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:fldSimple w:instr="MERGEFIELD firstname \* MERGEFORMAT">
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:noProof />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>John</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:fldSimple>
   </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

After the XSLT my output should be an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<w:hdr mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
   <w:p w:rsidR="00235C27" w:rsidRDefault="00235C27">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:fldSimple w:instr="MERGEFIELD firstname \* MERGEFORMAT" w:fldLock = "1">
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:noProof />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>John</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:fldSimple>
   </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

Please advise me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick. It copies all elements using the identity transform, and then handles `w:fldSimple`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
      version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <!-- Modify the identity transform to slip in the extra attribute -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:if test="name()='w:fldSimple'">
            <xsl:attribute name="w:fldLock">1</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(The attribute is added first, but this shouldn't matter)

```
  <w:fldSimple w:fldLock="1" w:instr="MERGEFIELD firstname \* MERGEFORMAT">
```

Comment: I tried it worked. Can you briefly explain the above piece of code?

Comment: The [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) is an common pattern used to recursively copy an xml document piece by piece. I've hacked *identity* by 'sneaking in' the attribute you need by looking out for `w:fldSimple`. More usually, you should keep the identity transform 'pure' and then explicitly have other templates subscribing to changes - e.g. as per my [earlier edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21041939/revisions). However, since this seemed a one-off attribute transformation, I mangled it into *identity* for brevity.

Comment: I have followed one of my existing xslt code to achieve this behavior. But it is giving an error saying that "XML document must have a top level element".
Please find the below code:

Answer (score 0):

Kindly let me know whether this code is possible?
@StuartLc Because I don't know about Identity transform, Please let me know is the code given by you secure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(),'w:fldSimple')">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:attribute name="w:fldLock">
           1
        </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```